# How can I get the object of modified str class from a Treeview's selection method?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a tkinter GUI program. For some purpose, I created a class "Str" inherited from the built-in class "str", to whose instance, I can bind some properties I need later. Everything went well until I transferred the "Str" object `some_string` to a Treeview's instance via `insert("", "end", some_string)` as id and get it via method `selection()`, I found what I got is not a "Str" object which is what I want actually but "str" instead.
I would appreciate it if someone could explain why, and it's even better to help me get a "Str" object from `selection()`. And my "Str" class is as follows:

```
class Str(str):
    def __new__(self, ID, title):
        return str.__new__(self, ID)
    def __init__(self, ID, title):
        self.title = title
```

Comment: This approach simply isn't going to work.  The actual data being displayed in a Tkinter GUI does not exist in Python at all; it's in an embedded Tcl/Tk interpreter.  Nothing other than a plain string can be transferred between the two environments, so your custom subclass gets lost.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your illustration. It seems that there is no simple way to work it out.